# Facebook access token extending - "The access token does not belong to application xxx"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I went to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET, set up there ID of my Facebook page, set up there the correct permission for posting statuses on my FB timeline and generated access token.

Then I wanted to extend this short-live token on the long-term (60 days long valid token). So I did following - I put this URL to the browser:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID_OF_MY_FB_APP&client_secret=SECRET_ID_OF_MY_APP&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=GENERATED_ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_THE_FIRST_STEP
```

and in the browser I saw this error message:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "The access token does not belong to application APP_ID_OF_MY_FB_APP",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1
   }
}
```

Which is weird, because the APP_ID of my Facebook app is correct, I've tried to post on the wall of the Facebook page and it was working.
But when I try to get extended access token, I am getting the error above.

What's wrong with the access?

Thank you

Comment: Pls chk the access token that you are sending in the debugger tool

Answer (score 3):

This almost certainly means what the error says, which is that `GENERATED_ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_THE_FIRST_STEP` is not actually from the app ID that you're using in the `APP_ID_OF_MY_FB_APP` parameter

Check the access token you're trying to extend in  [Facebook's Debug Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug)and ensure it was actually generated for your app

Answer (score 0):

Your AppID param is not the same to the AppID in developers.facebook.com